# Ruby on Rails - Select in form helper always saves first option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I'm working on a project where when a user is created they should be added to a team. The list of teams updates when new teams are created.

However, every time I save a user the team is saved as the first item in the drop down.

```
  <%= f.label :team %>
  <%= f.select :team, {}, {}, id: :user_team do %>
      <% @teams.each do |team| %>
        <%= content_tag :option, team.name, value: team.id %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

controller:

```
def create
team = Team.find_by(params[:user_team]).id

user = User.new(user_params)
user.team_id = team

if (params[:user_admin] == '0')
    user.admin = 'false'
else
    user.admin = 'true'
end

if (user.valid?)
    user.save
    redirect_to "/users/#{user.id}"
else
    flash[:notice] = user.errors.full_messages
    redirect_to '/users/new'
end
```

end

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :username, 
  :password, :password_confirmation, :admin, :team)
end
```

Comment: Can you show your controller, rendered form, and submitted params?

Comment: Seconding the rendered form. My guess is that `<%= content_tag :option, team.name, value: team.id %>` is probably not doing what you'd think, or that you'll need a prompt or `include_blank` argument.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but you could try adding a placeholder element, either by passing a `include_blank: true` to your select ERB tag, or by providing an option with an empty value like this: `<option value="">Select One</option>`. The former would be the more 'rails-y' way to do it, as documented here: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select

To build on that, what I think is happening is that your select always has the first element selected by default because there is no prompt or placeholder. If that's the case, then if you don't actively change it then it'll send the value of the first option every time.